# when i am trying to use the instance of operator to compare integer object with String object its throws a compile time error.

Tags: java

*when i am trying to compare two objects of a class it works perfectly, but it doesn't work when i am trying with some predefined class objects 'like Integer object with String object etc. want to know why it is.*

Comment: Show some code. Read [mcve] and [ask].

Comment: An Integer can never be a String. `instanceof` is not allowed whenever the compiler knows it will always return false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you mean is that something like this does not compile:

```
String text = "Hello";
if (text instanceof Integer) {  // Error, inconvertible types
    // ...
}
```

The Java compiler is smart enough to see that `text` is a `String`, which can never be an instance of `Integer`, so the condition would always be false - it doesn't make sense to do this kind of thing, so it's forbidden according to the rules of the Java programming language.

This is specified in [paragraph 15.20.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.2) of the Java Language Specification, which says:

> If a cast ([§15.16](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.16)) of the *RelationalExpression* to the *ReferenceType* would be rejected as a compile-time error, then the `instanceof` relational expression likewise produces a compile-time error. In such a situation, the result of the `instanceof` expression could never be true.

Comment: oh yeah got it thank you so much sir.....

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have:

```
Integer five = 5;
String abc = "abc";
Object fiveRef = five;
Object abcRef = abc;
```

`fiveRef == abcRef` is correct because in this case you compare two refs. and it will be true only if left and right refs to the same object;

`five == abc` is always false, because of different types of refs. So compiler is smart to check it.